# Is it possible to establish connection from backend server to Android phone, based on Google Account

Tags: android, networking

I'm wondering if there's any way to realize the following: I want to write an application that can establish a network connection from my desktop computer(s) to my phone in certain situations. I don't want it to be based on the IP-address since that's of course unpredictable as the phone moves through the network and changes from network to wireless (not to mention firewall restrictions, NAT etc.). So I'm wondering if Google has an API/mechanism that can be used to establish a connection based on the Google account (essentially the e-mail address) that the phone is using. Surely, Google must have some mechanism like this since it is possible to remotely install software on Android phones (by i.e. going to the Play Store on your desktop, finding an application and selecting you want it installed on your phone) and it doesn't require any special configuration beforehand. But what I'm interested in knowing is whether this mechanism is publicly exposed and could be used by a custom app?

Thanks!

Comment: I think title might be better served if you mention pc in the title.

Comment: Thanks, I've clarified the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's what Google uses to install apps on device:

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

You could theoretically use the same tool.
The phone receives the cloud message and it initiates the connection without your home network. Probably this message would/could have your home network PC- addressing so it knows where to connect to.

But the problem is that for this to work you need your own server running on the cloud to receive a message from the user computer, use the data in that message to create the GCM and send it to Google.

Comment: Great, thanks! This is just what I was looking for. And it appears Google is adding an XMPP-based bidirectional variant (CCS = Cloud Connection Service), which might remove the need for my own server running in the cloud. Again, thanks.